# parfor problems: only one process is running

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, ubuntu-12.04, parfor

I have parfor loop in matlab, when it is running, only one process is using CPU (Top and system monitor shows same CPU usage,see attached screenshot), and the parfor doesn't run faster. Why???

ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64bits matlab 2012b

```
pools = matlabpool('size');
if pools ~= 10
    if pools > 0
        matlabpool('close');
    end      
    matlabpool local 10;  %10+ the one I am using = 11 matlab process in system monitor
end

parfor i = 1:num_utt

 dojob();

end
```

[image]

Thanks, Marcin & Edric,

I had run a small test case as you suggest, and then I noticed that the problem is caused by the inner loop code access outer loop data,  in this http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/advanced-topics.html , they call it as access broadcast variables.

> At the start of a parfor-loop, the values of any broadcast variables
>   are sent to all workers. Although this type of variable can be useful
>   or even essential, broadcast variables that are large can cause a lot
>   of communication between client and workers. In some cases it might be
>   more efficient to use temporary variables for this purpose, creating
>   and assigning them inside the loop.

For my case the broadcast variable holds lots of data, so it has problem to pass it to the worker.

After I remove some of the data, the parfor loop works fine.

Comment: what does `dojob` do? does the problem occur if you have just e.g. rand(10000); instead of dojob()?

Comment: Looking at the PIDs, it appears that the MATLAB using all the CPU is your client MATLAB, not any of the workers. I would adjust @Marcin's suggestion and use something like `parfor ... max(abs(eig(rand(200)))), end` as that is computationally intensive without using up too much memory.